# How to add custom http header in go fasthttp ?

Tags: http, go

I am using a fasthttp server https://github.com/valyala/fasthttp

I need to add a custom header for all requests

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 4):

Since it's a response header i assume you mean this:

```
ctx.Response.Header.Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option if you are not using `Context`:

```
func setResponseHeader(h http.HandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    }
}
```

`setResponseHeader` is essentially a decorator of the argument `HandlerFunc` `h`. When you assemble your routes, you can do something like this:

```
http.HandleFunc("/api/endpoint", setResponseHeader(myHandlerFunc)) 
http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

To enable CORS support on fasthttp, better use [fasthttpcors](https://github.com/AdhityaRamadhanus/fasthttpcors) package.

```
import (
    ...
    cors "github.com/AdhityaRamadhanus/fasthttpcors"
    ...
)

func main() {
    ...

    withCors := cors.NewCorsHandler(cors.Options{
        AllowMaxAge: math.MaxInt32,
    })

    log.Fatal(fasthttp.ListenAndServe(":8080", withCors.CorsMiddleware(router.HandleRequest)))
}
```